# Смена значения даты по умолчанию в MySQL

Tags: mysql

В MySQL таблице нужно сменить значение по умолчанию

```
datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

на

```
datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01'
```

Все попытки поменять его ни к чему не привели.

Запросы выполнения ниже:

Запись в таблице при создании:

```
'post_date' datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Проверенные запросы:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER post_date SET DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01'
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE post_date SET DEFAULT datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE post_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE post_date DATETIME  NULL DEFAULT NULL`
```

Выдает ошибку: `Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'post_date'`

В результате нужно получить:

```
datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01'
```

Comment: Какая версия mysql?

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение, что вы решаете не ту задачу. Зачем вам ставить такое значение по дефолту?

Comment: Изменение дефолтного значения выполняется запросом `ALTER TABLE .. CHANGE COLUMN ..`. Обратите внимание - имя поля указывается в нём **ДВА РАЗА**. Старое и новое (возможно, то же самое). Либо используйте запрос `ALTER TABLE .. ALTER COLUMN ..`.

Comment: См. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ee3e70a20decdefea2659992b0bb3f22)

Comment: Пробую в приложении MySql Workbench, не работает, все равно ругается на Invalid default value for 'post_date'

Comment: См. Server SQL Mode...

Comment: Версия mysql 5.7.26-29

Comment: Нужно сделать - поправить поля даты на "strict mode" чтобы не было значений типа "0000-00-00", Проверил "sql_mode" - указано в значениях "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" и "NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE". Насколько я понял, ничего менять не нужно, поправьте если ошибаюсь, спасибо.

Comment: И почему я делаю смену дефолтного значения ```datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'```, потому что мне нужно сменить  кодировку таблиц на ```utf8mb4_unicode_ci```, а без смены дефолтного значения ```datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'```, не хочет менять кодировку выдает ошибку ```ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'post_date'```

Comment: В моем случае помогло решение - ```ALTER TABLE `table_name` 
CHANGE COLUMN `post_date` `post_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01'```

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае помогло решение - **`ALTER TABLE`table_name`CHANGE COLUMN`post_datepost_date`DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01'`**